# How I do implement sonar+failsafe+jacoco?

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-failsafe-plugin

I try to implement sonar+failsafe+jacoco plugins. I added theese to my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and I added this plugins to the same file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <argLine>--add-modules java.base</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName> <!-- default: argLine -->
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile> <!-- agent -->
                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile> <!-- report -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and It is already exists in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${it.skip}</skip>
                    <argLine>--add-modules java.base</argLine>
                    <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*IT</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <doc.skip>${doc.skip}</doc.skip>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and I run *mvn clean verify -P integration-test* and then *mvn sonar:sonar*
but I still get a coverage is 0.0% Why did not get IT's reports results? Please help me.. What is my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a mistake, which I think is the cause of your problem:

In the configuration for `jacoco-maven-plugin` you overrid the parameter that would receive the jvm arguments set by jacoco to communicate with maven surefire, with `<propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>`. That means that it will fill in this property instead of the default property `argLine` (which is fine but not necessary I guess).

In the configuration for `maven-surefire-plugin`, you overrid  the `<argLine>--add-modules java.base</argLine>` (which by default would have taken the value `${argLine}`) without refering to the property `jacoco.agent.argLine`.
You need something like `<argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine} --add-modules java.base</argLine>` or `<argLine>@{jacoco.agent.argLine} --add-modules java.base</argLine>` (with an `@`) depending on your jacoco version.

If using `$`and not `@`, you may need to define an empty `<jacoco.agent.argLine/>` property on top of the pom file.